# unrecognizedPacketType, Actor server1.conn1.tabDescriptor1 does not recognize the packet type 'attach'

Tags: debugging, firefox, jetbrains-ide, rider

I tried debugging Firefox with Jetbrains Rider. But i got the error `unrecognizedPacketType, Actor server1.conn1.tabDescriptor1 does not recognize the packet type 'attach'` .

**Followed link**: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-firefox.html#ws_js_debugging_in_FF_debugging_session

Versions:

- Rider(2020.1.3)
- Firefox Developer Edition(79.0b3)

Is there still a bug of Firefox, or Rider is not fully supported? Please help me!

Thank in advance!
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 7/2020**

I asked on the JetBrains site. They said that due to changes in FireFox API. Debugging in Firefox now is not supported. They will fix it soon!.

Comment: I had the same problem using these versions:
 - Rider 2019.3.2 and Rider 2020.1.4
 - Firefox Developer Edition 79.0b9 (64-bit)

Comment: and you still have it right? @Pippolino

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using a JavaScript Debug configuration works but if I really need it I just use the Debug tab in the Firefox dev tools